# How to make a spinning wheel to display while loading an lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to render the page only after spinning wheel is getting loaded first. but here both are rendering at the same time(i.e spinning wheel and below component)

The code i used is

```
<aura:handler event="aura:waiting" action="{!c.showSpinner}"/>
<aura:handler event="aura:doneWaiting" action="{!c.hideSpinner}"/>
<center><ui:spinner aura:id="spinner"/></center>
```

In Controller Section:

```
showSpinner : function (component, event, helper) {
    var spinner = component.find('spinner');
    var evt = spinner.get("e.toggle");
    evt.setParams({ isVisible : true });
    evt.fire();    
},

hideSpinner : function (component, event, helper) {
   var spinner = component.find('spinner');
   var evt = spinner.get("e.toggle");
   evt.setParams({ isVisible : false });
   evt.fire();    
}
```

[image]

Comment: if the below answer proved useful, consider accepting it so ti may help others as well

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using $A.enqueueAction, then neither event fires initially on page load. Instead, set the default isVisible value to false.

```
<ui:spinner aura:id="spinner" isVisible="False" />
```

If you're using an init handler that includes a call to $A.enqueueAction, you don't need to specify the isVisible attribute, because aura:doneWaiting will hide the spinner for you when the action completes.